# How can I display GeoTIFF image in VC++?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, display, visual-c++

I need to represent a GeoTIFF file in a VC++ separate window where I can see the TIFF image and when the mouse is moved it display the geographic latitude and longitude. If I display a TIFF, before converting to GeoTIFF file, with the sentence "img.display()" I can see the pixel image's value and the pixel number (row, column).

Is it possible? I'm noob and I have no experience. Also I'm using libgeotiff in my program.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

This would need more than a few lines of code if you start from scratch. I suggest that you have a look at the [GDAL API for C++](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) (quite straightforward to extract the raster size etc.) and at the [orfeo toolbox](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/SoftwareGuide/) (uses FLTK for visualization).